# apache url rewrite: optionally rewrite path to querystr

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I understand RegEx fairly well but with the apache rewrite I am running in some issues.

First of all I can't get `rewrite:trace3` to write into my error log, so hard to see how Apache is evaluating the rewrite rules.

The rewrite rules are located in my .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule "^/?([^/]*/)$" "/handler.cfm?key=$1" [NC,QSA]
```

I have the following url:

```
subdomain.topdomain.com/12345/?test=foo
```

This needs to be rewritten to:

```
subdomain.topdomain.com/handler.cfm?key=12345&test=foo
```

For this I use the following rewrite (that works):

```
RewriteRule "^/?([^/]*/)$" "/handler.cfm?key=$1" [NC,QSA]
```

However, when I serve the url

```
subdomain.topdomain.com/?test=foo
```

it won't find the key part and the rule fails.

There is already a question mark in front of the capture group so I assume it is optional. Still it won't execute this rule.
With that I mean to say that it won't call the handler.cfm file but is looking for an index.cfm (which I don't have on that domain).
Index.cfm is set in my apache conf file as the start point for execution. But for this site I am not using it, only handler.cfm.

How do I capture the URL with no Key in the path and rewrite it to the handler.cfm file including querystrings?

I am happy to have a result like

```
subdomain.topdomain.com/handler.cfm?key=&test=foo
```

EDIT:
Log from rewrite enginge:

```
[Thu Oct 29 23:30:16.308083 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 9832:tid 140489839859456] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.5:63079] 192.168.1.5 - - [tracker.fyndle.local/sid#7fc66348fc28][rid#7fc6634050a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/fyndle/tracker/root/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/fyndle/tracker/root/ ->

[Thu Oct 29 23:30:16.308457 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 9832:tid 140489839859456] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.5:63079] 192.168.1.5 - - [tracker.fyndle.local/sid#7fc66348fc28][rid#7fc6634050a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/fyndle/tracker/root/] applying pattern '^([^/]*)/?$' to uri ''

[Thu Oct 29 23:30:16.308485 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9832:tid 140489839859456] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.5:63079] 192.168.1.5 - - [tracker.fyndle.local/sid#7fc66348fc28][rid#7fc6634050a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/fyndle/tracker/root/] rewrite '' -> '/handler.cfm?key='

[Thu Oct 29 23:30:16.308493 2015] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 9832:tid 140489839859456] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.5:63079] 192.168.1.5 - - [tracker.fyndle.local/sid#7fc66348fc28][rid#7fc6634050a0/initial] split uri=/handler.cfm?key= -> uri=/handler.cfm, args=key=&url=http%3A%2F%2Fproject-beauty.local%2F&_d=1446010350336

[Thu Oct 29 23:30:16.308579 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 9832:tid 140489839859456] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.5:63079] 192.168.1.5 - - [tracker.fyndle.local/sid#7fc66348fc28][rid#7fc6634050a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/fyndle/tracker/root/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/fyndle/tracker/root/ with /

[Thu Oct 29 23:30:16.308585 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 9832:tid 140489839859456] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 192.168.1.5:63079] 192.168.1.5 - - [tracker.fyndle.local/sid#7fc66348fc28][rid#7fc6634050a0/initial] [perdir /var/www/fyndle/tracker/root/] internal redirect with /handler.cfm [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

Comment: Please post your rewrite rules in context of the apache config file. By your use of `^/` and it working correctly some of the time, I assume this is inside a .conf file in `<Directory>` or `<VirtualHost>` context rather than in .htaccess, correct?

Comment: Also, how do you know it is looking for `index.cfm`? Do you see a redirect actually changing the browser URL bar? If so, you may be seeing the browser try to visit a cached redirect URL from some other earlier attempt. What you've posted here in and of itself would never cause a rewrite to index.cfm unless there's an ErrorDocument pointing there (and maybe a few other possibilities)

Comment: It's in a .htaccess file, added it to the question. I know it is looking for index.cfm because my coldfusion error message tells me: `Page /index.cfm [/var/www/project/tracker/root/index.cfm] not found`. Index.cfm is the default document to revert to. So I am just wondering if it is possible to have the Url without a key ( example: `subdomain.topdomain.com/?test=foo~`) also rewrite to the handler.cfm file

Comment: So I got my trace:3 logging working now. However, I not sure if it is a rewrite issue. When there is no folder set after the domain extension, there is nothing to capture I reckon. I do see in the log that it tries to redirect ` [perdir /var/www/project/tracker/root/] internal redirect with /handler.cfm [INTERNAL REDIRECT]` but it ends up trying to load the index.cfm set in the .CONF file as document index. I am not sure why it not just goes to handler.cfm. I guess my wish was for nothing to end up in the index.cfm. For now I can live with creating the index.cfm and keep it empty.

Comment: This would mean that any request without a key after the domain extension would be lost because it ends up at index.cfm. Is it possible to redirect/rewrite the request the has an empty capture group?

Comment: In .htaccess, the uri passed to RewriteRule does not include the leading slash, so your pattern may never properly match.  I would expect the answer below to do what you need, as it removes the leading `/` and makes an optional trailing one.